# How to use WSL2 as a Jenkins agent machine from Jenkins on Windows 10?

Tags: jenkins, wsl-2

Is it possible to use WSL2 as an agent for Jenkins installed in Windows 10 x64?

Answer (score 4):

As long as you can SSH to your WSL2 instance, using for instance 
[Scott Hanselman's script](https://gist.github.com/daehahn/497fa04c0156b1a762c70ff3f9f7edae?WT.mc_id=-blog-scottha) described in his [blog post](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/how-to-ssh-into-wsl2-on-windows-10-from-an-external-machine), that means your Jenkins main controller can contact the WSL2 instance through SSH.

[image: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/resources/node/node-2.png]

The alternative would be to use an agent with Docker.
Both methods are described in Jenkins documentation [Using agents](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-agents/).